# System.Windows.Controls.DocumentViewer print create extra spacing between characters on windows 11

Tags: .net-6.0, xpsdocument

I create an xps document with QuesdPdf and post it to System.Windows.Controls.DocumentViewer.
Document appears in the viewer normally.

[image]

But after printing to pdf or xps document extra spaces created between some characters as below image.

[image]

The problem only occurs on Windows 11 not in Windows 10.
My app is a .net 6.0 WPF application.

I tried different fonts and printer drivers. Which printer driver or font I use does not change the result.